# Ways to plot rectangular window function (u[n]-u[n-5]) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot the rectangular window function Graph in MATLAB for:-

```
x[n] = u[n] - u[n-5]
```

I have written the following MATLAB Code for the same:-

```
x = [ones(1,5), zeros(1,43)]
```

**But, this works only for a specific number of points on a graph (for ex: 48 points for this graph)**

I wanted to ask whether there is a better way to plot the rectangular window function plots in MATLAB for a discrete time signals? Thanks for the help:)

Comment: `x = [ones(1, 5), zeros(1, length(y) - 5)];` ? Having called your signal `y`

Comment: @MatteoV Yes, that's exactly what I did! Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm gonna copy it as an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling your signal `y`,

```
x = [ones(1, 5), zeros(1, length(y) - 5)];
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to create a function for this:

```
x=@(n)double(floor(n)==ceil(n)&n>=0&n<=4);

nn=(-4:24)/4;
subplot(211);
stem(nn,x(nn));
subplot(212);
stem(nn,x(nn-1));
```

Notice that `x()` returns 0 for non-integer `n`, which may or may not be sensible depending on how you use the function.

Answer (score 1):

### Using Anonymous Functions/Function Handles

To create a discrete plot that has unit step function I usually like to declare the unit step beforehand and use that in larger function. Here I use anonymous functions/function handles which are indicated by the `@()` holding the input parameters. In this case the only input parameter is `n`. The vector `N` can then be passed to `x()` and it'll plot all the `x[n]` values respectively. `Density` can be used to play with the number of stems plotted as well as `Start_Index` and `End_Index`.

[image: Discrete Plot Diagram]

```
Start_Index = -10;
End_Index = 10;
Density = 1;
N = (Start_Index:Density:End_Index);

%Unit step function%
u = @(n) 1.0.*(n >= 0);

x = @(n) u(n) - u(n-5);

stem(N,x(N));
title('x[n] = u[n] -  u[n-5]');
xlabel('[n]'); ylabel('x[n]'); 
ylim([0 1.1]);
grid on
```